# How to display some text inputs based on a combobox selection?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using the [Fields Factory plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/), I created the following attributes for my product:

[image]

As you can see, there are several predefined sizes and an item with "Custom size". How can show the measurement fields (Chest, Waist, Hips, ...) only when "Custom Size" is selected?

Comment: For The Custom Fields. I'm using a FIELD FACTORY plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title, body and tags of the question, so that it attracts answers. In further questions tag the relevant technologies (your fields plugin works with woocommerce, so thats worth a tag). Leave unnecessary information out of the question, focus on the relevant parts. Good luck!

Comment: You should provide the code that you are using to display / check / save that fields… Without this question is between unclear and too broad

Comment: Im not sure about the code, as m using Attributes based on default WooCommerce settings, followed by using a Plugin for Custom Fields. 

All i want is if a user clicks CUSTOM ORDER, the custom fields THEN appear.